# Обработка событий в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Моя цель - обработать событие загрузки приложения, при этом применяя паттерн MVVM.

1. Насколько допустимо обработать его просто запихав обработчик в cs код окна?
2. Возможно ли обрабатывать такие события с помощью команд? Если да, то как? Все примеры команд которые я просматривал срабатывали лишь при клике.
3. Есть ли какой-то другой способ обработать события не нарушая "заповедей" MVVM?

Comment: Что за `событие загрузки приложения`? Если речь идет об `Loaded` событие окна (например), то вот вам [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593720/window-load-event-in-mvvm) и событие отловите и командой обработаете. Ну а так, вопрос не очень понятен, стоило бы конкретней написать что именно вы хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно подключить в xaml

```
xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

и привязать событие загрузки к своему свойству

```
<Grid>
    <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowLoaded}"/>
        </intr:EventTrigger>
    </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

cs

```
public class TestViewModel 
{
   public ICommand WindowLoaded { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        WindowLoaded = new RelayCommand(Load);
    }

    private void Load(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Загрузка");
    }
}
```

RelayCommand

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс описывающий реализацию интерфейса ICommand, для связываний событий из XML и кодом C#
/// </summary>
public class RelayCommand : ICommand 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// делегат, который будет выполнять действие
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    /// <summary>
    /// делеагат, который будет проверять разрешение на выполнение команды
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// можно ли выполнять команду или нет
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">функция, в которой происходит проверка на выполнение</param>
    /// <returns>можно или нет выполнить(true или false)</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// выполнение команды
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">функция, которая будет выполняться</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  добавления и удаления подписчика 
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```